# Spring @RestController cannot return unicode

Tags: java, spring-mvc, unicode, utf-8, spring-restcontroller

I have a simple RestController which returns a unicode string:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
public class FooController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test() throws Exception {
        return "ỗ ẵ ẫ ậ ự";
    }
}
```

But when run, it displays just **"? ? ? ? ?"**, How can I resolve this problem, I already had this configuration in web.xml:

```
   <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

And when I test with simple HttpServlet, it can return above unicode string.

Comment: What is `Content-Type` of your response header?

Comment: @Reno I did not set.

Answer (score 1):

In case others encounter the same...
Add **Produces** annotation with charset=utf-8
Then use **Response** object like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN + ";charset=utf-8")
public class FooController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Response test() throws Exception {
          return Response.status(HttpStatus.OK).entity("ỗ ẵ ẫ ậ ự").build();
    }
}
```